# VS Code change color of find all matches in side/scroll bar area

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code with doing a find and pressing alt + enter will highlight/mark all the occurences with an orange dash on the sidebar. Is there a way to modify this color? As seen in the picture of the minimap, we can see the three orange matches of the matches.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following setting:

```
"editorOverviewRuler.findMatchForeground": "#80CBC4"
```

The theme color API can be [found here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color). Scroll down to the "Overview ruler" settings in the ["Editor colors" section](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors) to find other similar settings.

Comment: Thanks. But that wasnt it. I tried setting all the properties of `editorOverviewRuler` to red just to test, but marker line is still yellow. it also appears that `editorOverviewRuler.border` is missing, so i am not sure if it is deprecated. i am on latest vscode

Comment: @securisec Make sure you save your settings. Also try reloading VSCode and then doing the find again.

Comment: Ahh. its not exactly, what i aws looking for, but it will do. It doesnt change the dash color, but it does put a blob of color which is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following two settings:

When you select --> "editorOverviewRuler.selectionHighlightForeground": "#d114b9",

When you highlight --> "editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground": "#00ffd9",